# What is the recommended place to store attachments?

Tags: support, meta

**Edit:** *In the case where it is not possible to provide sufficient detail or example input in the question text,* which service should I use to store files related to questions I ask?  (I.e. additional files related to my specific example which may assist in solving the problem.)

I see three types of hosting:

- Social network sites tied to public accounts, e.g. Google Drive, One Drive, etc.
- A workplace or private web server, e.g. http://company.com/SO/Example.pdf
- Anonymous sites for file swapping, e.g. Mega, Dropbox, etc.

I have several pros and cons for each alternative above, (e.g. privacy, permanency, reliability, workplace site restriction policies, etc.)

I wonder if this has been thought through before (I couldn't find a similar question) or if I could get some considered advice which may encourage others to avoid the pitfalls.

I am *not* wanting opinions on which hosting service is the "best".
I would promote this Wikipedia page as a useful resource for comparison:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_hosting_services

Comment: Keep questions or answers self contained as much as possible! There's no need for _attachments_ in 1st place!

Comment: None of the above. Put everything necessary to understand your question in the question itself. If you can't distill things to that point, figure out how to do so; that process will probably result in your figuring out the problem, and you won't need to post. Questions asked here should be self-contained, so that the information is always readily available to users in the future who have a similar problem (or solution).

Comment: I agree that concise, simplified examples are ideal.  My question was on the occasions where details DO matter and conciseness can not be achieved by pasting, what is the preferred alternative (besides asking somewhere else).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you start thinking of including *additional* files in hopes that it may clarify your question, **your question is decidedly unclear.**  You should always strive to keep your questions well-contained; that is, someone could, at their leisure, pull your code into their favorite IDE or editor and run it as-is (within limits; some third-party libraries that are used in the code should be mentioned).

There is ***no*** good place to host that content, since if they go dark, or you decide to remove it in an effort to clean up old stuff, Stack Overflow would still be live, and your supporting material wouldn't exist.  This would put anyone else looking for that question in a bind, since now they don't have the full picture.

Always strive to write the [most minimal code that exhibits the same behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as the code you're using.

Comment: I agree there is no ideal place to put sample files off site, and definitely agree that minimal code posts are best.  I can't agree that an additional file indicates an unclear question.  In this instance I was trying to include example input, which was a PDF.

Comment: I think your question may be clear but is just not suitable to be asked at this site, because such types of questions may violate the scope of this site (But, to be honest, according to former part of this answer, I can conclude that this site should cancel the upload image function because questions should not have additional files)

Comment: @amuse Images are included, inline, in the question. Very different from links to hosted code files. Stack Overflow has an agreement with imgur (the site that hosts images uploaded to SO) that they will not be deleted, unlike the file hosting services outlined in the question.

Comment: So this answer just confuse me, what is the problem of attachment? Is it because it is unclear? or it is just because of the removal of attachment afterwards? or both are reasons? Up to now cannot see very clear descriptions about that

Comment: @amuse:  Your question should be self-contained and complete.  If you have to rely on another party for hosting, it's not self-contained.  If they go dark when someone decides to stumble across the question, then that doesn't make for a good experience for someone either looking for that question, or trying to answer it.

Comment: I am not opposing the requirement of self contained, just wondering why additional files means unclear. According to the answer (I understand), if a question needs attachment, hosting the attachment outside would become "unclear", but if one day the site supports attachments and move the question attachment into this site, the question with automatically become "self contained", just feel strange about it.

Answer (score 8):

> I see three types of hosting:
>
> - Social network sites tied to public accounts, e.g. Google Drive, One Drive, etc.
> - A workplace or private web server, e.g. http://company.com/SO/Example.pdf
> - Anonymous sites for file swapping, e.g. Mega, Dropbox, etc.

There's ***no best place*** recommended to link for off-site resources actually, since you're required to put all the necessary information into your question/answer.

You may feed that up with references to online compiled code, that proves to show the problems that you observe with your code sample, or other helpful links.
But these never would be accepted as primary source, describing your problems clearly in a question.